# <asp:loginview> issue

Tags: 2010

i was following this tutorial by randy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430141.aspx
but when i tried to paste this code to master page :

```
<div class="customTopLeft"> 
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server"> 
<AnonymousTemplate>
<div class="customLogin"><a href="/_layouts/authenticate.aspx">User Login</a></div>
<style type="text/css">
body #s4-ribbonrow {
display: none;  }
</style>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
<style type="text/css"> 
.customLogin {
display: none;  }
</style>
</LoggedInTemplate>
<asp:LoginView>
</div>
```

i got error, loginview is not recognize something. anyone could helped me with this ? i guess i put it on the wrong place ? Cheers.

N

Answer (score 2):

Try this code now! it works:)

```
<div class="customTopLeft"> 
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server"> 
<AnonymousTemplate>
<div class="customLogin"><a href="/_layouts/authenticate.aspx">User Login</a></div>
<style type="text/css">
 body #s4-ribbonrow {
 display: none;  }
 </style>
 </AnonymousTemplate>
 <LoggedInTemplate>
 <style type="text/css"> 
 .customLogin {
 display: none;  }
 </style>
 </LoggedInTemplate>
 </asp:LoginView>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether you made a Copy/Paste error or what but you seem to have a few errors in your code...

You didn't closed the opening DIV tag and the opening STYLE tag...
If it's only a copy paste error, im sorryo to have made this pointless remark.
Elsen try testing it again when you corrected those mistakes. 
(tho i guess it will be a copy paste error)